# Jquery script inside the loaded layer is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code snippet in jquery when we click on layer 62 which loads a layer "loaded-page" from a page test.html as follows.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#62').on('click', function(e) {

$("#62" ).load( "test.html #loaded-page" );

});

$('#loaded-page').on('click', function(e) {
alert('test');

 });
 }); 

 </script>

 <div id="62">Layer62</div>
```

Test page coding

```
 <div id="loaded-page">Loaded page</div>
```

MY issue is when we click on layer loaded-page inside DOM, the alert test is not functioning. Can anybody suggest a solution for this ? If needed I can prepare a fiddle for this

Comment: Yes. It's event delegation.  Search for "javascript event on dynamically added content".

Comment: @Cale Thanks, can you provide a simple solution for that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/870729), but essentially what you are looking for is [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

When you bind the event in your code, that element doesn't exist yet.

So, you bind the event differently, so that it will respond to dynamically added content:

```
$(document).on('click', '#loaded-page', function(e) {
    alert('test');
});
```

NOTE: Without knowing your html structure, I can't provide the best solution, but I CAN tell you that you *do not* want to use `document` if possible.  Instead, you should use the nearest parent that exists when the DOM is initially loaded.  In your case, my guess is that this would work:

```
$('#62').on('click', '#loaded-page', function(e) {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I suggest using body is better than a selected layer #62

Answer (score 0):

because that when you bind the

```
$('#loaded-page').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('test');
});
```

maybe that the `#loaded-page` element is not be loaded into the document,so can't find it
the better way is :

```
$(document).delegate('#loaded-page','click',function(){
  alert('ok')
```

})

Comment: So how should the OP fix this? (Make your answer good, so future visitors looking for this may upvote it)

Comment: oh,so sorry ,i'm new here  ,i  get it

Comment: You should edit the answer - people in the future will up vote if it's high quality.